# Using Alt instead of Ctrl for vim-tmux-navigator

Tags: neovim, tmux

I recently configured `vim-tmux-navigator` and I'm enjoying it.  However, the binding of `ctrl-K` overrides the `kill` to end of line command in the terminal and I use this a lot.  As such, I want to bind to `Alt` equivalents rather than `Ctrl`.

I made the following changes to the NeoVim plugin configuration.

```
diff --git a/lua/custom/plugins/init.lua b/lua/custom/plugins/init.lua
index 9215d83..c81bb77 100644
--- a/lua/custom/plugins/init.lua
+++ b/lua/custom/plugins/init.lua
@@ -13,11 +13,11 @@ return {
       "TmuxNavigatePrevious",
     },
     keys = {
-      { "<c-h>", "<cmd><C-U>TmuxNavigateLeft<cr>" },
-      { "<c-j>", "<cmd><C-U>TmuxNavigateDown<cr>" },
-      { "<c-k>", "<cmd><C-U>TmuxNavigateUp<cr>" },
-      { "<c-l>", "<cmd><C-U>TmuxNavigateRight<cr>" },
-      { "<c-\\>", "<cmd><C-U>TmuxNavigatePrevious<cr>" },
+      { "<m-h>", "<cmd>TmuxNavigateLeft<cr>" },
+      { "<m-j>", "<cmd>TmuxNavigateDown<cr>" },
+      { "<m-k>", "<cmd>TmuxNavigateUp<cr>" },
+      { "<m-l>", "<cmd>TmuxNavigateRight<cr>" },
+      { "<m-\\>", "<cmd>TmuxNavigatePrevious<cr>" },
     },
   }
 }
```

And to the `tmux` configuration.

```
diff --git a/.tmux.conf b/.tmux.conf
index 21da869..e1249fa 100644
--- a/.tmux.conf
+++ b/.tmux.conf
@@ -18,19 +18,19 @@ set -g history-limit 8000
 # See: https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator
 is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
     | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|l?n?vim?x?|fzf)(diff)?$'"
-bind-key -n 'C-h' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-h'  'select-pane -L'
-bind-key -n 'C-j' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-j'  'select-pane -D'
-bind-key -n 'C-k' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-k'  'select-pane -U'
-bind-key -n 'C-l' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-l'  'select-pane -R'
+bind-key -n 'M-h' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-h'  'select-pane -L'
+bind-key -n 'M-j' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-j'  'select-pane -D'
+bind-key -n 'M-k' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-k'  'select-pane -U'
+bind-key -n 'M-l' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-l'  'select-pane -R'
 tmux_version='$(tmux -V | sed -En "s/^tmux ([0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?).*/\1/p")'
 if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$tmux_version < 3.0" | bc)" = 1 ]' \
-    "bind-key -n 'C-\\' if-shell \"$is_vim\" 'send-keys C-\\'  'select-pane -l'"
+    "bind-key -n 'M-\\' if-shell \"$is_vim\" 'send-keys C-\\'  'select-pane -l'"
 if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$tmux_version >= 3.0" | bc)" = 1 ]' \
-    "bind-key -n 'C-\\' if-shell \"$is_vim\" 'send-keys C-\\\\'  'select-pane -l'"
+    "bind-key -n 'M-\\' if-shell \"$is_vim\" 'send-keys C-\\\\'  'select-pane -l'"

-bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-h' select-pane -L
-bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-j' select-pane -D
-bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-k' select-pane -U
-bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-l' select-pane -R
-bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-\' select-pane -l
+bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'M-h' select-pane -L
+bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'M-j' select-pane -D
+bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'M-k' select-pane -U
+bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'M-l' select-pane -R
+bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'M-\' select-pane -l
```

This works in NeoVim and in `tmux` but not in both together.  How can I fix my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tmux part of configuration is wrong:

```
+bind-key -n 'M-h' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-h'  'select-pane -L'
+bind-key -n 'M-j' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-j'  'select-pane -D'
+bind-key -n 'M-k' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-k'  'select-pane -U'
+bind-key -n 'M-l' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-l'  'select-pane -R'
```

See `send-keys`, they should send `M-h/j/k/l` instead of `C-h/j/k/l` to the vim process.

Comment: Beautiful! Works like a charm.